# What kind of math equation would you use to rotate vertices on a 3d plane around certain point?

Tags: math, 3d, vb6, vertices

My friend and I are working on a doom like game in visual basic 6. We have previously found a sample program we used to create something that could render vertices on a 3d plane. We were only able to use the sample program to rotate on the Y axis in the corner of the group of vertices. But we want to be able to rotate the vertices from a different point.

```
What we are using to rotate vertices around origin point:

Temp(Current_Vertex).X = (Vertex_List(Current_Vertex).X * Cos(Angle_Y * RADIAN)) + (Vertex_List(Current_Vertex).Z * Sin(Angle_Y * RADIAN))
Temp(Current_Vertex).Y = Vertex_List(Current_Vertex).Y
Temp(Current_Vertex).Z = (Vertex_List(Current_Vertex).X * Sin(Angle_Y * RADIAN)) - (Vertex_List(Current_Vertex).Z * Cos(Angle_Y * RADIAN))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a matrix and linear algebra:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: We aren't fully understanding how a rotation matrix works. We thought that was what we were doing. added another method we tried that didn't work.

Comment: You can't code what you don't understand.  The math in the citation is correct.  If your code isn't, you should review the math carefully to see where your translation into code went wrong.  Find someone who knows how to do matrix mutliplication.

Comment: We have been able to rotate the vertices around the origin point but we are trying to rotate them around a different point. Question is worded pretty bad so I will try to fix it.

Comment: @user3446820 To rotate around another point, you need to multiply your rotation matrix with a translation matrix. A translation matrix in 3D is 4 rows by 4 columns. Yes, it gets complicated. May I suggest you take a deep breath and read some 3D matrix tutorial ?

Comment: I see how it works now. We obviously have never worked with this kind of stuff before and we didn't really know how to ask this question to begin with.